# How to construct a nested list from another list with "begin" and "end" flags in python?

Tags: python, recursion, nested

I am trying to parse a file, which has a nested structure to the data it contains. The number nesting is arbitrary in depth, and each is demarcated by a string, e.g. 'begin' and 'end. I would like to construct a list (or dictionary, etc.) that preserves the nesting of the data structure in the file.

As a simple example, from a list that looks something like:

```
input = [0, 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 'end', 6]
```

I want to get to:

```
[0, [1, 2, [3, 4], 5], 6]
```

I tried creating a recursive function to do this, but I was unable to get the correct output. (I would include my attempt at a solution, but I can't tell if I am close or not at all because of the recursion). How should this problem be tackled?

Edit to add my attempt (I hope this doesn't just confuse things):

```
input = [0, 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 'end', 6]

def create_nest(items, nest):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if item == 'begin':
            nest.append(create_nest(items[i+1:], []))
        elif item == 'end':
            return nest
        else:
            nest.append(item)

nested_list = []
create_nest(input, nested_list)
```

This outputs:

```
[0, [1, 2, [3, 4], 3, 4], 1, 2, [3, 4], 3, 4]
```

Comment: If you post what you tried, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: The bug in your code is that after the recursive `create_nest` has been called, you're still processing the next items, so every nested item is double-counted.

Comment: Thanks, I have added my attempt. It's probably way off, but any help to set me in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: @BoppreH Thanks, adding `return nest` after the recursive call now gives me `[0, [1, 2, [3, 4]]]`, so I guess that is an improvement, but obviously I'm still missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive function, an iterator to avoid having to keep track of the current item, and taking advantage of the mutability of lists:

```
def to_nested(inpt, out=None):
    it = iter(inpt)   # use an iterator
    if out is None: # optional: just to avoid using a list as default
        out = []    #
    for item in it:
        if item == 'begin': # if begin, let's start a new level
            out.append([])  # add a new list and pass this recursively
            to_nested(it, out=out[-1])
        elif item == 'end': # if end, let's finish this recursion
            return
        else:               # else, add an item to the current level
            out.append(item)
    return out

to_nested([0, 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 'end', 6])
# [0, [1, 2, [3, 4], 5], 6]
```

*Note that this assumes a correct format (as many ends as there are begins). If not, you would have to keep track of them.*

##### modification of your approach using an iterator like I did

```
inpt = [0, 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 'end', 6]

def create_nest(items, nest):
    items = iter(items)
    for item in items:
        if item == 'begin':
            nest.append(create_nest(items, []))
        elif item == 'end':
            return nest
        else:
            nest.append(item)
    return nest

nested_list = []
create_nest(inpt, nested_list)
# [0, [1, 2, [3, 4], 5], 6]
```

Comment: Using `iter` is a really smart solution to avoid double-counting items.

Comment: @BoppreH thanks, I love iterators and generators for that, it's very easy to do complex things without needing to keep track of the state ;)

Comment: `iter` is also good since the real version of this problem will be using `open()`, which returns an object with this behaviour already, no?

Comment: @Idle_92 yes, then no need to convert to iter (although it would still work)

Answer (score 2):

Done without recursion:

```
def collapse(lst):
    save = []
    curr = []
    for x in lst:
        if x == 'begin':
            save.append(curr) # remember what you had so far
            curr = []         # start over
        elif x == 'end':
            old = save.pop()  # get back what you had
            old.append(curr)  # add list you just finished
            curr = old        # pick up where you left off
        else:
            curr.append(x)
    return curr
```

Comment: Avoiding recursion has always been my go to approach, so thank you for providing this solution. I will accept the other answer here though, since it provides a working version of the solution I was attempting.

Answer (score 1):

Linear datum are best processed with a linear procedure -

```py
def parse(tokens):
  r = [[]]
  for t in tokens:
    match t:
      case 'begin':
        r.append([])
      case 'end':
        r[-2].append(r.pop())
      case _:
        r[-1].append(t)
  return r[0]
```

```py
parse([0, 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 'end', 6])
```

```py
[0, [1, 2, [3, 4], 5], 6]
```

You can and should exceptions for malformed `begin..end` pairs -

```py
def parse(tokens):
  r = [[]]
  for t in tokens:
    match t:
      case 'begin':
        r.append([])
      case 'end':
        if len(r) < 2:
          raise RuntimeError("unexpected 'end'")
        r[-2].append(r.pop())
      case _:
        r[-1].append(t)
  if len(r) > 1:
    raise RuntimeError("expected 'end'")
  return r[0]
```

```py
parse([0, 'end', 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 'end', 6])
# RuntimeError: unexpected 'end'
```

```py
parse([0, 'begin', 1, 2, 'begin', 3, 4, 'end', 5, 6])
# RuntimeError: expected 'end'
```

Elegant as they may be, the recursive solutions here provided incorrect output for malformed inputs.